# Looking for a jQuery plugin that implements dialog docking

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I need to create the ability to "dock" dialogs (in a browser page) to each other. I'm using "dock" in the sense that MS Visual Studio is using for the windows inside the IDE (where you can make them "dockable"). The user should be able to slide a dialog until its edge hits another window. Then both of them can be dragged together as one (or something very similar.

A jQuery plugin that implements this is preferred.

Answer (score 4):

[Link to Advanced-docking-using-jQuery](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/05/30/Advanced-docking-using-jQuery.aspx) is the closest I could find. It gives you dock like in visual studio however without the drag and move. It may give you a starter for 10 as your requirements are very specific and I am sure you will have to roll your own.

Comment: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/06/01/Advanced-docking-using-jQuery.aspx